How can I simulate driving a high capacitance MOSFET with a gate driver IC?
I'm trying to drive a MOSFET with approximately 2nF of capacitance, using a 1EDN7511B gate driver.
Following the data sheet sample circuit, I created this:

and tried to simulate it on LTSpice using the model published by Infineon.  However, I get just a flat output:

Is my circuit incorrect? Or is my circuit correct but the simulation broken? The simulated model SUBCKT has "pins" for ambient and junction temperature - is that the problem?  How can I get a good circuit here?

Update
Simulation or not, it would be enormously helpful if someone could answer

Simulator or not, will the schematic above work in real life?

Netlist
As requested, here is the netlist:
* C:\LTspice\Gate_Driver.asc
XIC1 Vosc N001 0 Vcc Drive Drive NC_01 NC_02 1EDN7511B
Vcc Vcc 0 12V
R1 0 N001 100k
V1 Vosc 0 SINE(5 5 4Meg)
Rload Drive 0 1Meg
C1 Vcc 0 1µF
.lib 1EDN7511B.lib
.tran 0 11u 10u 1n
.lib C:\LTspice\1EDN7511B.lib
.backanno
.end


periblepsis test
The test requested by periblepsis produces 787mV on Vdd:



Solution
As recommended by Jonathan S., reducing the pull-down to 1K solves it! I'm baffled as to how from the data sheet I could see to do that.


First, read any documentation from Infineon, and/or look for example circuits.  If you can't find anything, then second, assume that no connection means you're trying to operate the chip at absolute zero.  Third, try 300V, assuming that it's 1V/Kelvin, and see what happens.

The schematic is based on an example circuit from the data sheet.  The actual IC doesn't have "TAMB" or "TJ" pins - these are somehow part of the simulation.  I tried adding voltage sources to them, but no result.

@SRobertJames It looks like TAMB and TJ are outputs, not inputs. However, there doesn't seem to be documentation on them, either. TAMB, for example, seems to be a 1k resistor in parallel with a 1nF capacitor and driven by a G voltage source. I'd probably wrap this SUBCKT with another one that doesn't expose those two.

@SRobertJames I'm a little concerned about all the moving parts in that model. (Which is actually lots of SUBCKT's being called.) There may be some keywords (in either spice) that aren't the same for each other. And it's possible that parameter passing in LTspice is a little different. You can debug the SUBCKTs, one by one, by going to the Control Panel for LTspice and selecting the Save Defaults tab and then checking the "Save Subcircuit Node Voltages". Then you can display them on the plots with a right click and "Add Traces". But this only works for named, not numbered, cards.

@SRobertJames Do a test for me. Disconnect your Vcc pin from the power supply voltage and insert an RC there, instead. Use 10 Ohms (or 20, something like that) and use a grounded capacitor of say 10 uF. Use a .TRAN card run for 100 ms or something like that. Put 0 V via 50 Ohms to IN- and 3.3 V via 50 Ohms to IN+. Stick 39 Ohms series resistor at SRC, 33 Ohms series resistor at SNK, tie their two loose ends together and to a 2.8 nF cap to ground (to simulate FET.) Then tell me the voltage at the Vcc pin of the IC package.

@SRobertJames No, I mean something more like this.

Your voltage source Vcc isn't actually connected to the chip. The net at its positive terminal needs a label, just like you did with the Vcc net label connected to the chip's VDD terminal.
Additionally, the 100k on the IN- terminal is not sufficient to overcome the chip's internal pull-up resistor. Try connecting it directly to ground instead (or lower the value of the resistor to 10k or less).
This is mentioned in section 4.3 of the datasheet of your driver:

The non-inverting input is internally pulled down to a logic low voltage. The inverting input is internally pulled up
to a logic high voltage.

The pull-up resistor value is given in table 11 of the electrical characteristics (section 5.4) as 400 kOhms. With a supply voltage of 12V and an external pull-down resistor of 100 kOhms, this only pulls the input down to 2.4V, which the driver is guaranteed to recognize as a logic high. As a result, the chip gets disabled.

@SRobertJames: The Vcc source is named Vcc, but the associated net at the source is not.

Jonathan S., @RussellH If you look at the 12V source in the upper right, the wire near the bypass cap is named Vcc.  It may be hard to see.  To test this, I added an explicit wire now, and the scope was identical.

@SRobertJames. I don’t see that. I see what RussellH sees, which is a reference designator for the voltage source named Vcc. Anyway, just make sure if you change the circuit in any way, that you close the waveform viewer before you rerun the simulation.

@SRobertJames If you want to put to bed these questions about your schematic, post up the netlist in your question. That will resolve all questions like this.

@periblepsis Done.  I also posted the test you recommended and got 787 mV.  What do you say?

@SRobertJames I had missed one more mistake in the schematic - IN- must be driven hard to ground. I've updated the answer.

The SIMetrix simulation file included in the .zip supports the suggestion for IN- being tied to ground.  https://i.sstatic.net/CbxPvyLr.png

Also, here's an LTspice simulation with it working now: https://i.sstatic.net/YgT0tox7.png

Wow! I reduced the resistor to 1K and it works! I'm baffled as to how I would know that, since MOSFETs usually work fine with very large pull down resistors.  Where in the data sheet could I find that?

@SRobertJames Your pulldown is fighting the pullup internal to the chip and isn’t strong enough to win at 100K. The edited answer shows this in more detail.
